# Mysterious getenv() seg faults

Tags: c, getenv

I am trying to export variable and read it back using `getenv()` but for some reason, it gives me a segmentation fault..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    system("export LINES=$(stty size | awk '{print $1}');"
        "export COLUMNS=$(stty size | awk '{print $2}')");
    printf("%s %s\n", getenv("LINES"), getenv("COLUMNS"));
    return 0;
}
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

The weird thing is that **it runs normally on gdb**, and the compiler output shows no error while compiling, even with `-Wall -Wextra`...
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The child process run by `system()` doesn't affect the environment of the process that calls `system()`.

Therefore, the shell executed by `system()` doesn't set `LINES` or `COLUMNS` in the environment of the calling process, so `getenv()` is probably returning a pair of null pointers, which is somehow causing grief…  Except that `printf()` often works correctly even when a null pointer is passed to it for formatting with `%s` (it produced `(null)` for me, but that is not behaviour mandated by the C standard).

If you want to set an environment variable, you should use [`setenv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setenv.html).  You may come across old code that uses
[`putenv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putenv.html) instead, but you should not use that in new code.

Comment: then can you explain why this is working when running on gdb?

Comment: @hoholee12, well `gdb` probably uses the ncurses library and exports `LINES` and `COLUMNS` variables to the subprocesses it spawns.  Then you get non-null values from `getenv(3)` and no error results from `printf(3)`.